# CGFLOAT_TYPE & Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

### My Situation:

I have learnt Swift for a while and Swift is my only language I've learnt for iOS Development, which means I did not learn Objective-C Systematically. I can just read OC Code a little.

I got a `Type Casting` problem when I tried to translate a OC project to Swift project.

I just confused about some `Type` in that OC code.

### Objective-C Code:

```
static inline CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat_ceil(CGFLOAT_TYPE cgfloat) {
#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE
return ceil(cgfloat);
#else
return ceilf(cgfloat);
#endif
}
```

### My Unproved Guessing：

1. I think this is a function to do some works like `Type Casting`, cast `CGFLOAT_TYPE` to different types based on the `#if` and `#else`.
2. After Google the `CGFLOAT_TYPE`, I got to know that all those uppercases  are `Assembly Language`.
3. And I also learnt that `CGFLOAT_TYPE` is declared in `CGBase.h`, a official framework, as the macro.

### My Problem:

1. When I tried to write the `CGFloat_ceil()` in Swift, I even can not find the `CGFLOAT_TYPE`. And I ready wrote the `import CoreGraphics` on the head of my file.
2. But When I wrote `#if CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE`&`#else`&`#endif`, those code just show on the screen with color, I mean, complier drop no error. But the complier can not recognize `CGFLOAT_TYPE` when I declared it.

### My Question:

1. Can those mysterious `CGFLOAT_` stuffs still be used in Swift?
2. I really be blocked in here. Please teach me how to translate those OC
   code to Swift?

A big appreciation to your guide and help.

Ethan Joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CoreGraphics framework defines `CGFloat` as

```
#if defined(__LP64__) && __LP64__
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE double
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
// ...
#else
# define CGFLOAT_TYPE float
# define CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE 1
// ...
#endif

typedef CGFLOAT_TYPE CGFloat;
```

so it is defined as `float` or `double`, depending on your platform.

But `<math.h>` knows nothing about `CGFloat`, it has
two different functions `ceilf()` and
`ceil()` for `float` and `double` parameters.

Your `CGFloat_ceil()`  now uses the `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` definition and the
preprocessor (not Assembly!)  to select the matching function
automatically.

**You don't need that in Swift.** Swift defines overloaded `ceil()`
(and other mathematical) functions for `Float`, `Double` and `CGFloat`
parameters, so

```
let x = ceil(someFloat)    // returns a Float
let y = ceil(someDouble)   // returns a Double
let z = ceil(someCGFloat)  // returns a CGFloat
```

all just work as expected.

Note also that in Swift – unlike (Objective-)C –, `CGFloat` is
not a simple type alias to `Float` and `Double`, but a different type.