# Swift equivalent of ceilf for CGFloat

Tags: swift, cgfloat, ceil

I was trying to do something like this

```
var myCGFloat: CGFloat = 3.001
ceilf(myCGFloat)
```

but `ceilf` only takes `Float` values. While searching around there were lots of different answers about doing this conversion or that depending on whether it is 32 or 64 bit architecture.

It turns out the solution is fairly easy but it took me too long to find it. So I am writing this Q&A pair as a shortcut for others.

Comment: Related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647127/cgfloat-type-swift.

Comment: @MartinR, Your answer there was what I was looking for yesterday, but my search keywords didn't turn it up. Thanks for posting the link.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Swift way to do this now is to use `rounded(.up)` (or `round(.up)` if you want to change the variable in place). [Behind the scenes it is using `ceil`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488326/3681880), which can take a `CGFloat` as a parameter and is [architecture independent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24182426/3681880).

```
let myCGFloat: CGFloat = 3.001
let y = myCGFloat.rounded(.up) // 4.0
```

This is equivalent to

```
var myCGFloat: CGFloat = 3.001
let y = ceil(myCGFloat) // 4.0
```

Any use of `ceilf` is no longer necessary.

See also [my fuller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34785079/3681880) answer on `CGFloat` with various rounding rules.